# How to abstract shared HTML from components with different event binding?

Tags: angular

I'm working on a project and I realize a lot of my components share an HTML snippet to something like:

```
<div class>
   <button type="button" (click)="example()">Label</button>
   ...
</div>
```

Each component has a different click binding, and I'd like to abstract the shared HTML part to a component keeping that in mind. I'm assuming working with routing is the way to go here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common HTML script can be moved into it's own component, which can then be re-used in other components that use the same HTML.

The HTML script could be wrapped into it's own component, *MyComponent* which encapsulates the HTML as it's template:

```
<div class>
    <button type="button" (click)="example($event.value)">Label</button>
    ...
</div>
```

You can also fire events from the shared component to the parent component using an output accessor and an emitter.

The shared component, *MyComponent* would have the output emitter and event handler declared as follows:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-component',
    ...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() clickEvent: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

...

example(event)
{
    this.clickEvent.emit(value);
}
```

Your shared component can then be used within another component's HTML template using an HTML tag of the selector of the new component:

```
<app-my-component (clickEvent)="eventClicked($event)"></app-my-component>
```

An event declared within the parent component would then handle into own events from event notifications from the child component:

```
eventClicked(value: any) {
    // do something with the value from the child component.
}
```

The above is a basic overview of encapsulating HTML into a shared component and serve as component building blocks within an Angular application.